# GPU memory update atomicity

Tags: cuda

I have a main global memory (`gpu_mem`), along with a variable (`gpu_mem_offset`) to track the current offset of this global memory where a thread will update its content. Will the following script guarantee the atomicity of both the memory content and offset values?

```
__global__ void kernel(int *gpu_mem, int *gpu_mem_offset)
{
    gpu_mem[(*gpu_mem_offset)++] = some_value;
}
```

**Update**

I quickly realized that the above script is stupid, but I did describe my intention: how to guarantee the atomicity of both the memory content and offset values? Or, how to lock both of them at the same time? Maybe not achievable?

Comment: In a word, no, whenever you run more than a single thread

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to ensure a consistent update of both counter and array in that example is like this:

```
__global__ void kernel(int *gpu_mem, int *gpu_mem_offset)
{
    int offset = atomicAdd(gpu_mem_offset, 1);
    gpu_mem[offset] = some_value;
}
```

i.e. if you need atomic updates, then use an atomic intrinsic. That is what they are for. Here the atomic access to `gpu_mem_offset` ensures every thread gets a unique value of the offset. Then the write is guaranteed to be safe, because each thread accesses a unique index.

Comment: It's so obvious. Sorry that I got stuck.

Comment: Keep in mind, that this approach only guarantees the writing consistency. If multiple threads do the same thing, they *will* write to different cells. However, this will fail if you try to read from the same array with different threads, e.g. when trying to do implement work-stealing FIFO queue. To do that you will need to do more...